# Random Forest Query

Tags: random, random-forest

I am working on a project based on random forest. I saw one ppt (Rec08_Oct21.ppt)(www.cs.cmu.edu/~ggordon/10601/.../rec08/Rec08_Oct21.ppt) 
regarding random forest creation. I wanted to ask a question. 
After scanning through the randomly selected features and their Information gain value, we select the feature with the max value of IG for feature j. Then, how do we split using this information? How do we proceed after this?

Answer (score 1):

```
LearnTree(X, Y)
```

Let X be an R x M matrix, R-datapoints and M-attributes and Y with R elements which contains the output class of each data point.

```
j* = *argmaxj* **IG** j // (This is the splitting attribute we'll use)
```

The maximum value of IG can come from either a categorical (text-based) or real (number-based) attribute.

---> If it's coming from a **categorical attribute**(j): for each value v in jth attribute, we'll define a new matrix, now taking *X* v and *Y* v as the input derive a childtree.

```
Xv = subset of all the rows of X in which Xij = v;
Yv = corresponding subset of Y values;
Child v = LearnTree(Xv, Yv);
```

*PS: The number of child trees will be same as the number of unique value v's in the jth attribute*

---> If it's coming from the **real valued attribute** (j): we need to find out the best split threshold

*PS: The threshold value **t** is the same value that provides the maximum **IG** value for that attribute*

```
define IG(Y|X:t) as H(Y) - H(Y|X:t)
define H(Y|X:t) = H(Y|X<t) P(X<t) + H(Y|X>=t) P(X>=t)
define IG*(Y|X) = maxt IG(Y|X:t)
```

We'll be splitting over this **t** value, we then define two ChildTrees by defining two new pairs of **X** t and **Y** t.

```
X_lo = subset of all the rows whose Xij < t
Y_lo = corresponding subset Y values
Child_lo = LearnTree(X_lo, Y_lo)

X_hi = subset of all the rows whose Xij >t
Y_hi = corresponding subset Y values
Child_hi = LearnTree(X_hi, Y_hi)
```

After splitting is done, the data is then classified.

For more information, [go here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAHOUT/Random+Forests)!

I hope I answered your question.

Comment: I upvoted for the general treatment. but the 'go here' link is broken.

Comment: [use this link](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAHOUT/Random+Forests) you can also have a look at my **java implementation** 
[here](https://github.com/crazyiitian007/RandomForest-Awesome)